# How to convert from to String to LocalTimeZone?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, cron

I am developing an application and gives me a problem in converting from String to LocalTimeZone. I have shown the problem with two screenshots below for a better view and understanding:

[image]
[image]
Than it's the Task class who defines the **model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task", schema = "public")
public class Task {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private Long id;

 @NotEmpty
 private String date;

 @NotEmpty
 private LocalDateTime startTime;

 @NotEmpty
 private LocalDateTime stopTime;

 @NotEmpty
 @Column(length=1000)
 private String description;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="USER_EMAIL")
 private User user;

 public Long getId() {
    return id;
 }
 public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
 }
 public String getDate() {
    return date;
 }
 public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
 }
 public LocalDateTime getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
 }
 public void setStartTime(LocalDateTime startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
 }
 public LocalDateTime getStopTime() {
    return stopTime;
 }
 public void setStopTime(LocalDateTime stopTime) {
    this.stopTime = stopTime;
 }
 public String getDescription() {
    return description;
 }
 public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
 }
 public User getUser() {
    return user;
 }
 public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
 }
 public Task(String date, LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime stopTime, String description, User user) {
    this.date = date;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.stopTime = stopTime;
    this.description = description;
    this.user = user;
 }

 public Task(String date, LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime stopTime, String description) {
    this.date = date;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.stopTime = stopTime;
    this.description = description;
 }

 public Task() {
 }
}
```

Here is are the functions that add new tasks in the database

```
@GetMapping("/addTask")
public String taskForm(String email, Model model, HttpSession session) {
    session.setAttribute("email", email);
    model.addAttribute("task", new Task());
    return "views/taskForm";
}
@PostMapping("/addTask")
public String addTask(@Valid Task task, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpSession session) {
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return "views/taskForm";
    }
    String email = (String) session.getAttribute("email");
    taskService.addTask(task, userService.findOne(email));
    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

And below is the function in another class which is needed for this task that I am asking.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0-59 * * * * ?")
public void cronTime() {
    logger.info("Cron Task : Execution Time - {}", dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
    System.out.println("Cron job is executed again!");
    List<LocalDateTime> a = taskService.stopTimeTasks();
    for (LocalDateTime tmp : a) {
        if (LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(tmp)) {
            taskService.deleteAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me if you have info for this error.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DateTimeFormatter as follow:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("10/11/2018");

LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm").parse("09:00");

LocalDateTime locaDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, localTime);
```

I would recommend you to change the domain model and accept LocalDateTime for startTime and stopTime with their dates. At this point you will save "10/11/2018 09:00" and "10/11/2018 18:00", it will be more easy to apply a sql filter between dates. I see unnecessary the date column.

Comment: Can you make a model for me please, because I made for example "10/11/2018 09:00" and "10/11/2018 18:00" we can register any time we want. How can I simplify more please?

Comment: your model is fine, I just see the date column as a duplicated value because your startTime and stopTime will have the date. BTW I commented your other post.

Comment: I just explained you in other post why I need startTime and stopTime

Comment: I know that your startTime and stopTime are fine. I'm just saying that the date column its seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: Ok I am deleting date column now, can you help me with cron jobs please?

Comment: I have applied 1 sql queries: to take all the stopTime in a List
`@Modifying
 @Query("select stopTime from Task") 
List<LocalDateTime> findStopTasks ();`

Comment: Please accept my answer if solved your problem. About your cron job, Are you deleting just old tasks? I don't know what your deleteAll() do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185014/discussion-between-fabio-plaka-and-wilder-valera).